# Host does not start

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

For some reason, the host stopped running.

Previously, the console wrote that everything was OK and the application was running on a specific IP, but now nothing is written and API methods are not available:

> There was an error connecting to
>   http://localhost:20019/api/User/Authorize)

[image]

At the same time, no exceptions. The only thing that I recently changed is the password in the account. If something was not enough, it should have been a timeout. What could be the problem?

```
 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .CaptureStartupErrors(false)
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseHttpSys(options =>
        {
            options.Authentication.Schemes =
                AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
            options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://*:20019");
            options.MaxRequestBodySize = config.GetValue<long?>("maxRequestBodySize");

        })
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
    var initializer = host.Services.GetService<IRepositoryInitializer>();
    initializer.Init();
    host.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
  .CaptureStartupErrors(true) // the default
  .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
```

instead?

Other ideas: https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/07/16/7-tips-for-troubleshooting-asp-net-core-startup-errors.aspx

Comment: Nothing changed. Chrome says it can't access the site.

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of waiting, the message appeared and the API started working.

[image]

All the following launches of the application began to be performed instantly.

Magick...